# How can I scan last 5 days for a function what is the code for PineScript Tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, lookback

Hello everyone I just can't fix a problem. I have signal code like that:

```
crossingrule = ta.crossover(line1,line2 ) or ta.crossunder (line1, line2) ? color.lime :color.orange
```

but when I check this on the screen. It gives me only the last bar's condition.

I want this code to scan last 5 days or like 2 days. how can I add a code what should I write and where)?

I found a code like barssince and it works but I don't want bars to be counted I want a specific time like "last 5 days". not "last 5 bars"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ta.crossover(Buy1,buy2)` returns True if:

- on the previous candle, the value of the Series `Buy1` was lower than the value of the Series `buy2`
- and on the current candle, the value of the Series `Buy1` is higher than the value of the Series `buy2`

This means the value of `Buy1` has crossed over the value of `buy2`.

Extending upon your comment I suggest a mechanical approach (especially if you are new to Pine).
To check for crossover on the current day, you'd use `ta.crossover(Buy1,buy2)` as above. To check if a crossover happened a day ago (provided you are on the Daily chart), you can do either:

```
- ta.crossover(Buy1[1],buy2[1]) OR
- ta.crossover(Buy1,buy2)[1] // I suggest this one
```

The crossover two days ago will be `ta.crossover(Buy1,buy2)[2]` and you get the idea for the rest. You can chain together a large condition or you can show the last 5 days on a row in your table.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I mean I want that. I can get a green and a red code with this code. and I show it on a table. but it shows me only the last bar condition. ı want this function to scan previous days and tell me : yes there is a crossover within the last 5 days. or there is not any crossover within the last 5 days.

Comment: Hey @BhryOzkn, I have extended the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot  I will try this